# List Hover issue

Tags: jquery, html, css

I've already asked this question, but I think I din't explain the problem well enough.  So here we go again:

[image]

I've got a list.  With a default background color as shown in the picture above.  I want to make **item 4** background change to color #EDEDED when hovered upon.  Only Item 4.  Item 3, item two should remain with the original background color.

How do I do that?  My problem has been that when I hover on item 4, all parent items get their background color changed to #EDEDED also.  Any JQuery or CSS solution is appreciated.

Here's the code for the list above:

```
  <ul>
    <li class='comment'>
      <div class='comment-body'>
        item 2
      </div><abbr class='timestamp' title='2011-02-18 11:39:32'>2011-02-18 11:39:32</abbr>
      <div class='aut'>
        Anonymous
      </div><a href='#comment_form' class='reply' id='2' name="2">Reply</a>
      <ul id='comments-ul'>
        <li class='comment'>
          <div class='comment-body'>
            item 3
          </div><abbr class='timestamp' title='2011-02-18 11:40:07'>2011-02-18 11:40:07</abbr>
          <div class='aut'>
            Anonymous
          </div><a href='#comment_form' class='reply' id='3' name="3">Reply</a>
          <ul id='comments-ul'>
            <li class='comment'>
              <div class='comment-body'>
                item 4
              </div><abbr class='timestamp' title='2011-02-18 11:40:12'>2011-02-18
              11:40:12</abbr>
              <div class='aut'>
                Anonymous
              </div><a href='#comment_form' class='reply' id='4' name="4">Reply</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li class='comment'>
      <div class='comment-body'>
        item 1
      </div><abbr class='timestamp' title='2011-02-18 11:39:28'>2011-02-18 11:39:28</abbr>
      <div class='aut'>
        Anonymous
      </div><a href='#comment_form' class='reply' id='1' name="1">Reply</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
```

Comment: Are there likely to be more nested items (more than 4 deep)? i.e. is it that you just want the deepest level item to respond to the hover state?

Comment: yes, there can be more neste item, beyond level 4.  I only want that level to respond, on which the mouse is being hovered and everything else remain the same...

Comment: can you use www.jsbin.com or any other to demonstrate in code what is happening so we could give you a better help ?

Comment: Sorry - you only want the 4th level to respond or you only want the deepest level to respond?

Comment: I want only that list item on which the mouse is being hovered to respond.  If it has a child, the child needs to remain the same original color, but the parent changes to the new color

Comment: Here we go, an example on jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/the_archer/DsAsj/6/  As you can see, if I hover on list item 4, list item 2,3 also get highlighted.  How do I make only list item 4 highlight on hover?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go:

```
$('li:not(:has(li))').hover(
    function() {
        $(this).css({'background': '#EDEDED'});
    },
    function() {
        $(this).css({'background': 'none'});
    }
);
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/a6LqJ/

Comment: This is nearly it! :)  But what about list item 3, and item 2.  What if I want them too to have their background color changed when hovered upon.  Say, I hover on item 3 - I only want item 3 to highlight, but not item 2 or item 4.  Simlilarly, if I hover on item 2, I don't want item 3 and item 4 to highlight.  Any ideas?

Comment: Ahhh - now I understand. I thought you were just wanting the deepest item to change. It's not possible with the HTML structure you have. The nested li items are "nested". The background colour will appear through.

Comment: Might need a bit longer ;) I will not be beaten by this!

Comment: alright.  Take your time.  But here's something:  Can it be achieved if I change the list/ul elements to div?

Comment: Are you able to modify the HTML? I managed to get it working this way: http://jsfiddle.net/a6LqJ/1/ - NB: you can't apply it to the li because the mouseover event isn't fired when you move from a child li to a parent li.

Comment: yes, I can add HTML.  :)  Nice job btw!  Very good.  I"m going to use it.  But before that, I'm nearly there with a solution of my own mixed with the code you provided above.  I'll post it here if it works.  Meanwhile, I accept this answer!  Thank you very much!

Comment: No problem. Keen to see what you come up with!

Comment: to hell with my solution.  It does work.  It's getting too complicated.  I'll go with yours.  Kudos for you not giving up on the problem...

Answer (score 0):

bind hover event for #comments-ul li, add a delay so that the other items do not display a background if the intent is item4 . you can try to use http://cherne.net/brian/resources/jquery.hoverIntent.html plugin